# Find string, do not append to file if not found

Tags: batch-file

Processing a large amount of data files using batch. The filename is passed from a previous batch file. I'm trying to strip out the data from the file and append it to four other files based on a string on each line. Sometimes the file will not contain all 4 prefixes, and I do not want to create a blank output file (it screws up data processing later). I'd prefer to put a condition that if `"A%file1%"` cannot be found, do not append. Rather than delete blank files at the end.

```
find <%1 "A%file1%," >>A%file%.dat
find <%1 "B%file1%," >>B%file%.dat
find <%1 "C%file1%" >>C%file%.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

FIND command return an errorlevel of 1 if the string was not found, or 0 otherwise. You can use this value after the find command to delete the empty file:

```
find <%1 "A%file1%," >>A%file%.dat
if %errorlevel% equ 1 del A%file%.dat
```